# AngularJS - Multiple non-nesting elements on a single app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have an app in which there are many elements spread all over the page. The highest element I could use for bootstrapping the app is the BODY element, however I do not want to do it like this.

I would like just to tell angular to bootstrap the same app over more elements which are not related in any way and share the data between it.

I've setup a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RMpvkSdDC6h1eyVh4l35), however it seems that a shared service is not the right way to go

Basically, in any of the textfields you'd change the text, it should propagate to the other one as well, however this does not happen.

What I am doing wrong? Is there a better approach to this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have not used `ng-app` anywhere. If I add `ng-app` as an attribute to the `html` tag, your code works

Comment: Multipe `ng-app` are not supported. Angular provides a construct of modules use that.

Comment: I do *not* want to put the ng app on the html tag nor bootstrap it there! Thanks!